# Pulling Single Quote From DB and displaying on page using Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.7

I have some quotes in a database and am trying to use Laravel to display it on a page. I have the quotes being pulled from the controller then passed to the view but I am getting an error:

```
Undefined variable: quotes (View: C:\laragon\www\resources\views\inc\quote.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\\resources\views\inc\quote.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\\resources\views\inc\quote.blade.php
```

QuotesController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class QuotesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $quotes = DB::table('quotes')->get();

        return view('inc.quote', ['quotes' => $quotes]);
    }
}
```

quote.blade.php

```
<div id="MarketingQuote" class="container-fluid padding bg-light">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h2>Marketing Quote of the day</h2>

            @foreach($quotes->all() as $quote)
                <li>{{$quote}}</li>
            @endforeach

            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <img src="img/computer.jpg" class="image-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Migration Table for Quotes

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
class CreateQuotesTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('quotes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->text('quote');
            $table->string('author');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('quotes');
    }
}
```

Why do I get this error? And how do I get only one quote to display at a time and only change upon each page refresh?

Thank you.

Comment: `$quotes->all()` should just be `$quotes`, but I am not sure that explains the error you're seeing.  Try `return $quotes;` in your Controller, make sure you are getting results and looking at the right method.  Check your routes - does `QuotesController `index()` really map to the route you are looking at?

Comment: Hi, So I am able to return all quotes to my view but I only want one quote to return at a time and want a different quote to appear on each page refresh? Right now this is my logic in my controller. How do I only return one quote. See Comment below:

Comment: class QuotesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $quotes = DB::table('quotes')->get();

        return view('home', compact('quotes'));
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to input the variable $quotes in the controller, And I remember the passed variable array key which can use and not have to use all function.

The below code from laravel manual:

```
Route::get('greeting', function () {
        return view('welcome', ['name' => 'Samantha']);
    });
    Hello, {{ $name }}.
```

change

```
@foreach($quotes->all() as $quote)
                <li>{{$quote}}</li>
@endforeach
```

into

```
@foreach($quotes as $quote)
                <li>{{$quote}}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate a little more on this? How would I place $quotes in the controller? I currently set that variable in the controller already?

Comment: @PA-GW Hi. You passed params in the controller which is a pair of key and value. So you should use the key as variables in view.

Comment: Hi, I updated my code to:  @foreach($quotes as $quote)
                <p>{{$quote->quote}}{{$quote->author}}</p>
            @endforeach    (How do I only return one quote at a time and a different quote on each page re-fresh?) Thank you.

Comment: Now foreach statement return an array and input each element. if you want make it come true, you should only pass one variable not an array.